# Multi-level sorting in Excel with ignoring empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula, multi-level

Multi-level sorting would probably be suitable for this task if there was an option “ignore empty cells”.

I need to sort the rows so that the sorting for column A ignores empty cells, and the sorting rule for column C is applied to rows with these empty cells.

But multilevel sorting simply moves rows with empty cells in column A to the end of the list, and only then does the sorting rule for column C apply.

Here's an example of what I mean.
Here's an unsorted list of random music bands:

| Band 1 | Info 1 | Band 2 | Info 2. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The Beatles. | some info... |  | some info... |
| Queen | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Radiohead | some info... |
|  | some info... | Nirvana | some info... |
| Coldplay | some info... |  | some info... |
| Metallica | some info... |  | some info... |
| U2 | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Pink Floyd | some info... |
| Red Hot Chili Peppers | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Imagine Dragons | some info... |

If I sort it using a multi-level sort with the first sorting rule on column A and the second sorting rule on column C, we have this result:

| Band 1 | Info 1 | Band 2 | Info 2. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coldplay | some info... |  | some info... |
| Metallica | some info... |  | some info... |
| Queen | some info... |  | some info... |
| Red Hot Chili Peppers | some info... |  | some info... |
| The Beatles. | some info... |  | some info... |
| U2 | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Imagine Dragons | some info... |
|  | some info... | Nirvana | some info... |
|  | some info... | Pink Floyd | some info... |
|  | some info... | Radiohead | some info... |

But the result I need looks like this:

| Band 1 | Info 1 | Band 2 | Info 2. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coldplay | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Imagine Dragons | some info... |
| Metallica | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Nirvana | some info... |
|  | some info... | Pink Floyd | some info... |
| Queen | some info... |  | some info... |
|  | some info... | Radiohead | some info... |
| Red Hot Chili Peppers | some info... |  | some info... |
| The Beatles. | some info... |  | some info... |
| U2 | some info... |  | some info... |

The real table is much more complex, and sorting methods with auxiliary columns are highly undesirable.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this sorting. But, it seems, I scoured the entire Internet. Perhaps I don’t know what this sorting is called correctly, and that’s why I couldn’t find

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the `Info` columns. How will they be sorted? You show them all identical in both pairs.

Comment: The data in the Info columns simply follows the rows as they sorted in other columns. They contain various information

Comment: Where should `INFO2` go if there is a blank in `BAND2`?

Comment: It should follow sorting rule of Band 1

Comment: I don't understand why, if you are ignoring the blank rows, your desired result has some of those blank rows now containing data.

Comment: The first sort rule ignores blank rows in the Band 1 column, but the second rule sorts those rows by non-blank data in the Band 2 column (and ignores the Band 1 column).

Comment: Could you share if the formulas in my answer handle the issue as expected? Also, you didn't add any tag on how you would like to handle it e.g. `vba`, `excel-formula`, `powerquery`... `ignore` and `cell` are useless tags in this case. I mean, there is nothing built-in in Excel.

Comment: I apologize for the long response. Unfortunately, there were a lot of difficulties on my part, since I am very new to such difficult tasks. I described this, and how I solved the problem, in more detail in my answer.
Your answers for the example table do handle sorting as I expected, but unfortunately I was unable to rewrite them for my table due to their complexity. More details about this are also in my answer

Answer (score 4):

## Multi-Level Sorting

[Initial Post and 1st Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77904773/3)

### 2nd (Relevant) Edit

**Inputs**

- `data` - the range (array) reference - self-explanatory
- `levels` (default is 2) - in the screenshot, the data has 3 levels and each level has 2 columns. The levels can have any number of columns but their number has to be the same. The columns are calculated in the formula based on the total number of columns in the range.
- `sort_col` (default is 1) - is the column to be sorted by. In the 1st screenshot, the data is sorted by the first columns (BoysN) and in the 2nd by the 2nd columns (GirlsN).
- `sort_order` (default is 1) - can be ascending (1) or descending (-1).

**Standalone**

- You can use it as is or create a Lambda out of it. In the initial post is a fairly good description of how to do it.

```
=LET(data,B1:G21,levels,3,sort_col,1,sort_order,1,
    GetLeftMostEntry,LAMBDA(data,
        INDEX(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,
            IFNA(XMATCH(TRUE,r<>""),1))))),
    SortByCol,LAMBDA(headers,data,sort_array,[sort_order],LET(
        so,IF(ISOMITTED(sort_order),1,sort_order),
        VSTACK(headers,DROP(SORT(HSTACK(
           sort_array,data),,so),,1)))),
    dd,IF(data="","",data),
    d,DROP(dd,1),
    f,CHOOSECOLS(d,SEQUENCE(levels,,,COLUMNS(d)/levels)+sort_col-1),
    SortByCol(TAKE(dd,1),d,
        GetLeftMostEntry(f),sort_order))
```

**Lambdas**

- You can use the following 3 Lambdas to create your own functions in the `Name Manager` and utilize them with e.g.

  ```
  =MLSort(B1:G21,3,2,-1)
  ```

  for girls descending.

GetLeftMostEntry

- In each row of an array, returns the left-most value that is not nothing (`<>""`) or not blank.

```
=LAMBDA(data,
    INDEX(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,
        IFNA(XMATCH(TRUE,r<>""),1)))))
```

SortByCol

- Stacks the sort array to the left of the data, sorts the data by it, drops it, and stacks the headers on top. It's kind of optimized for the `MLSort` function since the headers and the data are passed separately.

```
=LAMBDA(headers,data,sort_array,[sort_order],LET(
    so,IF(ISOMITTED(sort_order),1,sort_order),
    VSTACK(headers,DROP(SORT(HSTACK(
        sort_array,data),,so),,1))))
```

MLSort

- Uses the previous two helper Lambdas to perform a *"multi-level sort"* coined by OP.

```
=LAMBDA(data,[levels],[sort_col],[sort_order],LET(
    lv,IF(ISOMITTED(levels),2,levels),
    sc,IF(ISOMITTED(sort_col),1,sort_col),
    so,IF(ISOMITTED(sort_order),1,sort_order),
    dd,IF(data="","",data),
    d,DROP(dd,1),
    f,CHOOSECOLS(d,SEQUENCE(lv,,,COLUMNS(d)/lv)+sc-1),
    SortByCol(TAKE(dd,1),d,GetLeftMostEntry(f),so)))
```

**Three Levels - Boys ASC `sort_col=1`**

[image]

**Three Levels - Girls ASC (`sort_col=2`)**

[image]

Comment: To solve my problem, I used the example from your answer, where you suggested using an auxiliary column. If you return this part of the answer to the main post from the revisions, I will mark it as solved. I think that would be fair. In any case, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this array formula change the range to the actual size everywhere.
You can create it simpler with the LET function.

```
=IF(CHOOSEROWS(A2:D11,CHOOSECOLS(SORT(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(A2:D11,1)&CHOOSECOLS(A2:D11,3),ROW(A2:D11)-1,),1,1,FALSE),2))=0,"",CHOOSEROWS(A2:D11,CHOOSECOLS(SORT(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(A2:D11,1)&CHOOSECOLS(A2:D11,3),ROW(A2:D11)-1,),1,1,FALSE),2)))
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But the formula that I copy causes an error. I noticed that in the screenshots some parameters are separated by a ";" while in the text in those places there is simply ",". Simply replacing all commas with semicolons does not solve the problem. Perhaps this is a site layout problem. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: semicolon or colon is the app. separator setup character. My excel uses the semicolon separator. But the default is comma. Therefore on the screenshot you see semicolons. In the copiable formula  the default settings are applied. This is because of the decimal separator difference, which is the comma for me.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Edit:**
This code is been edited to adapt to any number of Band/Info pairs*

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Bands"]}[Content],
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(colNames, each {_, type text})),

    bands = List.Alternate(colNames,1,1,1),
    infos = List.Alternate(colNames,1,1,0),

//Unpivot the "Band" Columns
//Then sort by Band Name
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Changed Type", bands, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Columns",
        (x,y)=> Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase(x[Value], y[Value])),

//Create the different columns for the different bands
    colTypes= 
        Type.ForRecord(
            Record.FromList(
                List.Transform(
                    List.Repeat({type text},List.Count(colNames)), 
                        (t) => [Type = t, Optional = false]), colNames), 
            false),

    #"Added Custom"=Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows","Custom", (r)=> 
        Table.FromRecords(
            {Record.Combine(
                {Record.FromList({r[Value]}, {r[Attribute]}) &
                 Record.SelectFields(r,infos) })}), 
        type table colTypes),

//Cleanup        
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom"),{"Custom"})),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", colNames)
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: @ Tks. I am going to be making some edits so as to allow for more `Band/Info` pairs and a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the great answers!

*Unfortunately, there were a lot of difficulties on my part, since I am very new to such difficult tasks.
At first it turned out that Excel does not understand most of the commands (for example `SORT`) because it is licensed as Office 2016. But even after correcting the license to 2021 and reinstalling the entire Office package, problems with some other commands (such as `CHOOSECOLS`) remained. I never found out the reason for this. I had to completely reinstall Windows and the entire Office suite. And only after that I could start trying to check the answers.*

However, for the case of my real table, they turned out to be too difficult for me. In my real table, there were three pairs of columns to which this two-level sort needed to be applied in turn. And in some of them, the name of the Band was written in both Band 1 and Band 2 columns (the same). And I realized that I didn’t have enough skill to rewrite these great examples from the answers to suit my case.

In the end, **I simply resigned myself to three extra auxiliary columns, in which I simply wrote `=IF(A2="";B2;A2)`, and sorted them using regular multi-level sorting. I came to this solution thanks to the answer from VBasic2008, which can be viewed at the [link to the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77904773/3)**

I really appreciate everyone's really great answers and hope they help a lot more people. I really haven't found a single article describing such a task.

Comment: As written, the Power Query solution I provided will handle both of those cases without modification, and will work in 2016 (or 2021). Also, the `CHOOSECOLS` function did not appear until `365`

Comment: I won't roll back my post since it shows a solution for formulas in `M365` and I spent quite some time on it. You have correctly also supplied the link to the revision and explained what works for you. I think all of it should stay as-is for now or you should accept your own answer which explains everything.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld,
I tried this solution with Power Query. My first experience with it happened when I was creating this table, and it was quite easy and successful. But I’m not yet good enough to rewrite code of such complexity, it seems.

Comment: VBasic2008, 
I didn't mean to roll back the post. I meant to edit it again, adding that variant of solution there too

Comment: @Alekk32 There's no need to rewrite anything. The only change you'd need to make would be the name of the table in the 2nd line (the `Source` step) if that is something other than `Bands`.